# Restricting user to check checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a bunch of checkboxes, I would like to restrict the user to check the checkboxes based on selectbox value.

for example, if user selects value - 3 in selectbox, then he can only check 3-checkboxes(any three)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/8/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="count">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select><br/><br/>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" name="Data1" value="option1" />
  <label for="checkbox-1">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" name="Data2" value="option2" />
  <label for="checkbox-2">CSS</label>
   <br /> 
    <input id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" name="Data3" value="option3" />
  <label for="checkbox-3">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox" name="Data4" value="option4" />
  <label for="checkbox-5">CSS</label>
    <br />
     <input id="checkbox-5" type="checkbox" name="Data5" value="option5" />
  <label for="checkbox-5">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-6" type="checkbox" name="Data6" value="option6" />
  <label for="checkbox-6">CSS</label>
</div>
```

How can i do this? Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: for clarity: if the user selects `3` from the dropdown, does that mean he can check 3 checkboxes, or only `checkbox-3`?

Comment: yes, then he can only check 3 checkboxes. @hexblot

Comment: @Naresh Kamireddy - but which 3 checkboxes to show upons selection of 3 in the combo box ?

Comment: @Bibhu based on order

Comment: Please reword your question to give a specific example of which checkbox(es) should be check-able for a given single selection)

Comment: What should happen if they select three, check three, then change the select drop down to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean option val = 3 -> can check 3 checkboxes, then try this http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/9/

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#count').on('change', function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    });

    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
        if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > $('#count').val()){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: On the change of the select box this clears the already checked boxes, regardless of whether the number allowed is increased or decreased. Is this the behaviour the Asker wants? I figure, from a users perspective, when I click on a bunch of things and realise I'm one short, I shouldn't have to then re-check everything all over again..?

Comment: This solution breaks the checkboxes instead of disabling them.

Comment: @gvee clear already checked checkboxes is not the question of this topic, i just added this behaviour for testing.

Comment: @Pavlo restrict user to check checkboxes(can't see word 'disable') and how it breaks checkboxes?

Comment: There are no visual feedback that checking a checkbox won't work. Yes,  formally you've completed the task, but your solution isn't something that a designer would be satisfied with.

Comment: @Pavlo can you write why exactly, this is not good solution? i'm curiuos about it.

Comment: Ask this question on [UX Stackexchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). The comments here are not meant for a discussion like this.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated based on the helpful comments by Pavlo

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/23/

### JQuery

```
// Cache the selector
var checkBoxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

checkBoxes.click(function() {
    validateCheckboxes();
});


$('#count').change(function() {
    // Only neave the first N items checked (where N = number of items allowed)
    checkBoxes.filter(':checked:gt(' + ($(this).val() - 1) + ')').attr('checked', false);       
    validateCheckboxes();
});

function validateCheckboxes() {
    // If the number of checked items exceeds the number allowed
    if (checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length >= $('#count').val()) {
        // Disable all un-checked boxes...
        checkBoxes.not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        // We haven't hit out limit yet; make sure the checkboxes are still enabled
        checkBoxes.attr('disabled', false);
    }
};
```

Comment: Not bad, but the script shouldn't choose what to uncheck. (Why the first *N*, not the last *N* or random *N*?). Also selectors should be cached.

Comment: @Pavlo I did that based on my interpretation in the question comments: **Q:** "which 3 checkboxes to show upons selection of 3 in the combo box?". **A:** " based on order".

Comment: Fair enough. But `preventDefault`? It should be disabled, not broken.

Comment: Works well, you should update your answer (and cache those selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('input[id^="checkbox-"]').hide();

$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    for(i=1;i<=valueSelected;i++)
    {
        $('#checkbox-' + i).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single condition check with very minimal code :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(event){
    if($('div.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > $('#count').val())
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeevi/a5gUb/) fiddle example.