# check all checkboxes in a parent div, onclick using jQuery based on selectbox value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Here i want to solve two issues,

1. I've got a bunch of checkboxes, I would like to restrict the user to check the checkboxes based on selectbox value.
2. There are two div.checkbox, i want to check all checkboxes while clicking on parent div based on selectbox value

From above, i have solved first issue.

but how can i solve second one

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/HNmhL/13/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="count">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select><br/><br/>

<div class="checkbox" style='float:left;background:yellow;width:100px'>
  <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" name="Data1" value="option1" />
  <label for="checkbox-1">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" name="Data2" value="option2" />
  <label for="checkbox-2">CSS</label>
   <br /> 
    <input id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" name="Data3" value="option3" />
  <label for="checkbox-3">HTML</label>
  <br />
</div>

<div class="checkbox" style='float:left;margin-left:100px;background:brown;width:100px'>
  <input id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox" name="Data4" value="option4" />
  <label for="checkbox-4">CSS</label>
    <br />
     <input id="checkbox-5" type="checkbox" name="Data5" value="option5" />
  <label for="checkbox-5">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-6" type="checkbox" name="Data6" value="option6" />
  <label for="checkbox-6">CSS</label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#count').on('change', function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    });

    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
        if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > $('#count').val()){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: What does that mean: `There are two div.checkbox, i want to check all checkboxes while clicking on parent div based on selectbox value`?

Comment: @Naresh Kamireddy - Tell us what you have tried so far, this the soluton you received on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699839/restricting-user-to-check-checkbox-in-jquery

Comment: @Itay- if i'm clicking on a particular div, all checkboxes should checked in that div

Comment: @NareshKamireddy check my answer shorter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
   $('.checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
     if (e.target.className == "checkbox") {
         var cnt = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
         var cntSel = $('select').val();
         var fin = cntSel - cnt;
         $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:lt(' + fin + ')').prop('checked', true);
     }
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/16/)

Comment: @Anton i also want remove all checks, if i'm clicking 2nd on a div(i mean toggle)

Comment: @Anton - it is some what ok but, in this condition(selectbox value is 5) 2nd is div is not toggling

Comment: @NareshKamireddy I've made some changes, added data to the elements http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/26/

Comment: @Anton This is what i want

Comment: @Anton - here i have one more question, for every div there will be 'data-min' value. if minimum value is 2, then that particular div should compulsory have check 2 checkboxes(i.e, div should not have < 2 checkboxes). please can you help in this.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/18/)

shorter code :)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
        if ($('.checkbox').find('input[type=checkbox]').filter(':checked').length > $('#count').val()) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes your code shorter but, i want to check all checkboxes if i'm clicking on a particular div