# Unchecking checkbox value using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, alert

I am generating 5 checkboxes dynamically. I can select upto 3 checkboxes. Once 3 checkboxes are selected, If I try to select one more checkbox it should give an alert and once i click ok on the alert box the fourth checkbox that I have selected should be unchecked.

Code I am using for generating checkboxes dynamically

```
$("#catalog_table").append('<tr><td style="width:10%; background-color:#fcfbf6; font-family:Proxima Nova Regular; font-size:11pt; font-color:#443b33;text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:item();">'+productCatalog[i].productCode+'</a></td><td style="width:10%; background-color:#fcfbf6; text-align: center;font-family:Proxima Nova Regular; font-size:11pt; font-color:#443b33;">'+productCatalog[i].productName
                                                        +'</td><td style="width:10%;  background-color:#fcfbf6;  font-family:Proxima Nova Regular; font-size:11pt; font-color:#443b33; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" style="background-color:#fcfbf6;" name="chkOccupancy"  class="chkbox" value='+productCatalog[i].productCode+'></td></tr>');
```

I tried number of ways...but all are getting unchecked.Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @user2542428, please share the generated html output and of-course your js

Comment: try creating a fiddle for better results

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699839/restricting-user-to-check-checkbox-in-jquery/18700064#18700064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':checkbox').click(function() {
        if($(':checkbox:checked').length > 3){
            alert('you can not check more than 3 checkboxes');
            $(this).prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name=chkOccupancy]', function (e) {
        var chk = $(this);
        var cnt = $('input[name=chkOccupancy]:checked').length;
        if(3 < cnt) {
            chk.prop('checked', false);
            alert('Not more than 3 !');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, here's a non–jQuery option. You can put a single listener on an an ancestor element, say a div, and prevent a fourth checkbox from being checked:

```
function checkCBs(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el.type == 'checkbox' && document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length > 3) {
      el.checked = false;
  }
}
```

You might want to qualify the selector to keep it within the div or for inputs with a particular class. Sample markup:

```
<div onclick="checkCBs(event)">
  <label for="cb0">stuff<input type="checkbox" name="cb0" id="cb0">0</label><br>
  <label for="cb1">stuff<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1">1</label><br>
  <label for="cb2">stuff<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2">2</label><br>
  <label for="cb3">stuff<input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3">3</label><br>
  <label for="cb4">stuff<input type="checkbox" name="cb4" id="cb4">4</label><br>
</div>
```