# How to select last options user selected with shiny checkbox group input control

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, user-input

I have found the solution in the first answer to this question ([checkboxGroupInput - set minimum and maximum number of selections - ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139791/checkboxgroupinput-set-minimum-and-maximum-number-of-selections-ticks)) does not work as expected. The reproducible example is as follows:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

my_min <- 1
my_max <- 3

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("SelecetedVars", "MyList:",paste0("a",1:5), selected = "a1")
    ),
    mainPanel(textOutput("Selected"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$Selected <- renderText({
    paste(input$SelecetedVars,collapse=",")
  })
  
  observe({
    if(length(input$SelecetedVars) > my_max)
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "SelecetedVars", selected= tail(input$SelecetedVars,my_max))
    }
    if(length(input$SelecetedVars) < my_min)
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "SelecetedVars", selected= "a1")
    }
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When selecting checkboxes as you go down the list new selections are added to the tail of the input$SelectedVars vector and thus the tail(input$SelecetedVars,my_max) returns the last three vars the user selected. However as you go back up the list the vars are added to the head of the input$SelectedVars vector so tail(input$SelecetedVars,my_max) continues to return the vars already selected.

My current patch to this is to add a note on my app that says only three vars can be selected at a time. However this relies on the user to understand they have to un-check variables themselves. So for the sake of simplicity I am wondering if there is a way to have the most recent selected var to be appended to the tail of the vector so you can always display the last vars the user selected.

**EDIT 2020/12/17: Including new reprex to illustrate infinite cycling produced from @Ben's 2020/12/16 edit. I removed the min vars as well as this wont be used in my case.***

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

df <- aus_production # demo data from tsibbledata package

my_max <- 2

vars_list <- c("Beer", "Tobacco", "Bricks", "Cement", "Electricity", "Gas")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("SelectedVars", "MyList:",vars_list, selected = "Beer")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("plot1", height = "40vh"),
      textOutput("Selected"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  last_checked <- reactiveVal("Business")

  output$Selected <- renderText({
    paste(input$SelectedVars,collapse=",")
  })

  observeEvent(input$SelectedVars, {
    shinyjs::disable("SelectedVars")
    s <- input$SelectedVars
    isolate({
      if(length(s) > my_max)
      {
        removed <- last_checked()[1]
      } else {
        removed <- c(setdiff(last_checked(), s))
      }
      Sys.sleep(.5)
      complete <- c(last_checked(), c(setdiff(s, last_checked())))
      last_checked(complete[!complete %in% removed])
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "SelectedVars", selected = last_checked())
      shinyjs::enable("SelectedVars")
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$SelectedVars)
    vars <- input$SelectedVars

    df_plot <- df %>%
      select(Quarter:Tobacco)


    if(length(input$SelectedVars) ==  2){
      plot_ly(data = df_plot,
              type = "scatter",
              mode ="lines"
      ) %>%
        add_trace(x = ~Quarter,
                  y = ~df_plot[[2]]) %>%
        add_trace(x = ~Quarter,
                  y = ~df_plot[[3]])

    } else {
      plot_ly(df_plot) %>%
        add_lines(x = ~Quarter,
                  y = ~df_plot[[2]])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```